# MySQL for foreign key problems

Tags: mysql

Am having a problem with my MySQL code, I really don't know why

Am getting this error

#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

The problem is at table sales

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   idtel  varchar(100),
   username varchar(100),
   password varchar(100),
   email  varchar(100),
   role  varchar(15),
   credit INT(7),
   a_status varchar(100),
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   registered datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   updated datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

```
CREATE TABLE SALES (
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   username int,
   profit INT(7),
   sales INT(7),
   payments INT(7),
   balance INT(7),
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   FOREIGN KEY ( username ) REFERENCES USERS ( username )
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: I wouldn't store username in in sales - if you do then you have 2 maintenance points which gets a bit tricky if for example you correct the username in users suddenly the username in sales is all alone. Why not store user id in sales and fk that to users.

Answer (score 0):

In `MySQL`  [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) document we can found that

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key **must have similar data types**. The size and sign of fixed precision types such as INTEGER and DECIMAL must be the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same.

So the reason is that `username` in your two tables are not the same,I would suggest you change the `username` type in your second table

```
CREATE TABLE SALES (
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   username varchar(100),
   profit INT(7),
   sales INT(7),
   payments INT(7),
   balance INT(7),
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   FOREIGN KEY ( username ) REFERENCES USERS ( username )
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: like?, an example